# PHP Autocomplete not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've got all my html working correctly but there seems to be a problem with my php code when i try to autocomplete a field

```
search.php

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="js/jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="js/script.js"></SCRIPT>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

   <div class="main">
      <div class=""><a href="http://www.scriptime.blogspot.in">scriptime</a></span></div>
         <div id="holder"> 
         Enter Keyword : <input type="text" id="keyword" tabindex="0"><img src="images/loading.gif" id="loading">
         </div>
         <div id="ajax_response"></div>

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here my php code

names.php

```
<?php
    include("Connections/myphp.php");
    $keyword = $_POST['data'];
    $sql = "select username from ".$users." where ".$username." like '".$keyword."%' limit 0,20";
    //$sql = "select username from ".$users."";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        echo '<ul class="list">';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $str = strtolower($row['username']);
            $start = strpos($str,$keyword); 
            $end   = similar_text($str,$keyword); 
            $last = substr($str,$end,strlen($str));
            $first = substr($str,$start,$end);

            $final = '<span class="bold">'.$first.'</span>'.$last;

            echo '<li><a href=\'javascript:void(0);\'>'.$final.'</a></li>';
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    else
        echo 0;
?>
```

ajax code

```
/*
 cc:scriptime.blogspot.in
 edited by :midhun.pottmmal
*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        $("#ajax_response").fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $("#keyword").focus();
    var offset = $("#keyword").offset();
    var width = $("#keyword").width()-2;
    $("#ajax_response").css("left",offset.left); 
    $("#ajax_response").css("width",width);
    $("#keyword").keyup(function(event){
         //alert(event.keyCode);
         var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
         if(keyword.length)
         {
             if(event.keyCode != 40 && event.keyCode != 38 && event.keyCode != 13)
             {
                 $("#loading").css("visibility","visible");
                 $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "names.php",
                   data: "data="+keyword,
                   success: function(msg){  
                    if(msg != 0)
                      $("#ajax_response").fadeIn("slow").html(msg);
                    else
                    {
                      $("#ajax_response").fadeIn("slow");   
                      $("#ajax_response").html('<div style="text-align:left;">No Matches Found</div>');
                    }
                    $("#loading").css("visibility","hidden");
                   }
                 });
             }
             else
             {
                switch (event.keyCode)
                {
                 case 40:
                 {
                      found = 0;
                      $("li").each(function(){
                         if($(this).attr("class") == "selected")
                            found = 1;
                      });
                      if(found == 1)
                      {
                        var sel = $("li[class='selected']");
                        sel.next().addClass("selected");
                        sel.removeClass("selected");
                      }
                      else
                        $("li:first").addClass("selected");
                     }
                 break;
                 case 38:
                 {
                      found = 0;
                      $("li").each(function(){
                         if($(this).attr("class") == "selected")
                            found = 1;
                      });
                      if(found == 1)
                      {
                        var sel = $("li[class='selected']");
                        sel.prev().addClass("selected");
                        sel.removeClass("selected");
                      }
                      else
                        $("li:last").addClass("selected");
                 }
                 break;
                 case 13:
                    $("#ajax_response").fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#keyword").val($("li[class='selected'] a").text());
                 break;
                }
             }
         }
         else
            $("#ajax_response").fadeOut("slow");
    });
    $("#ajax_response").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find("li a:first-child").mouseover(function () {
              $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
        $(this).find("li a:first-child").mouseout(function () {
              $(this).removeClass("selected");
        });
        $(this).find("li a:first-child").click(function () {
              $("#keyword").val($(this).text());
              $("#ajax_response").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

when i try to search a name it give me an error saying : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where like 'ben%' limit 0,20' at line 1

Comment: how does the keyword get sent to the server? your code mentions ajax, lets see your javascript

Comment: @Mihai, its a column name

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select username from ".$users." where ".$username." like '".$keyword."%' limit 0,20";
```

you missed the `$users` and `$username`  what their values are?

Comment: that error means you sql has some problem and I think probably beacuse those to param have no value or have some strange values

Comment: after `$sql ="select....` put `echo $sql` to see what your sql query actually looks like

Answer (score 0):

2 Things:

I don't think you need `data:"data="+keyword`, looking at your php `data:keyword` will suffice.

Second,
try changing your query to:

`$sql = "select username from users where username like '".$keyword."%' limit 0,20";`

since your php does not seem to have `$users` or `$username` set.